# Checking if mouse buttons are down without listening to an event?

Tags: javascript

I'm building a dragging widget thingy, it listens to 'mouseup'/'mousedown' events from the interactive element.

Works fine most of the time but I've found the 'mouseup' to be a bit unreliable. Is there an event independent way of checking whether the mouse buttons are up/down? I could attach it to a timer or the mousemove event to make it foolproof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use an event however you can have script from within the events to assign the state of the mouse down that you can test later.

```
var isMouseDown = false;
document.addEventListener("mousedown", function()
{ 
  isMouseDown = true;
});
document.addEventListener("mouseup", function()
{
  isMouseDown = false;
});
if (isMouseDown == true) { ... }
```

Comment: `document` would be better than `document.body`, which may not fill the viewport. (And `.onxyz = ...` handlers don't play nicely with others.)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an event independent way of checking whether the mouse buttons are up/down?

No, there isn't. But for your dragging code, your best bet for listening for `mouseup` isn't the element you're dragging, but the document as a whole. You still won't get the event if the mouse release is outside the window, but you will if the mouse has been moved abruptly and released such that it's outside your element when the release occurs.

You can also listen for `mousemove`, which of course fires a **lot**, and also tells you whether buttons are down (via the `buttons` property on the event object).